Using Start-Process to launch PowerShell as an admin and run a command. How do I pass arguments to the command?
I have the following script to check if it's running as admin. If not, it launches a new window with the admin token and runs the script again in the admin window. The part I am unable to figure out, is how to pass the parameters originally sent to the script over to the newly launched script
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $Test1
)
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

if (-not $myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole)) {
    switch ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major) {
        5 {
            Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"{
                Set-Location -Path $pwd
                & '$PSCommandPath'
            }`""
        }
        Default {
            Start-Process PWSH -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"{
                Set-Location -Path $pwd
                & '$PSCommandPath'
            }`""
        }
    }
    exit
}
Write-Host $Test1
Write-Host "elevated"
(Get-Item -Path .\).FullName
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

Let's call the above script test.ps1. In a PowerShell window, I would call it as follows:
PS C:\>& .\test.ps1 -Test1 'SampleScript'
Since I'm passing a string at the time of calling the script, I would like this same string to be passed to the Administrative PowerShell that gets opened. So far, any attempts to pass the parameters have failed.
If possible, it needs to be versatile in that it passes all parameters that a script may have. The example above only has one parameter, but ideally even if the script has two or more all will get passed over to the admin window.

This should work for passing the bound parameters to the elevated script, might not be 100% robust but using an example of parameters (added a second $Test2 param for the example):
PS ..\pwsh> .\test.ps1 -Test1 123 -Test2 'a string with spaces'

Will output:
Elevated
D:\User\Documents\pwsh

Key   Value
---   -----
Test1 123
Test2 a string with spaces

This is the code for constructing the arguments by enumerating $PSBoundParameters. Note that -NoExit was added for debugging purposes, should be removed later on.
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $Test1,
    $Test2
)

$isAdmin = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
    [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).
        IsInRole('Administrators')

if (-not $isAdmin) {
    $pwsh = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path

    # NOTE:
    #   the use of `[CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent(...)` is required to properly escape
    #   possible single quotes `'` in arguments or the path itself
    $boundParams = $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
        ForEach-Object { "-$($_.Key)", "'$([CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent($_.Value))'" }

    $command = "
        Set-Location -Path '$([CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent($pwd))'
        & '$([CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent($PSCommandPath))' $boundParams
    "

    $arg = '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command "{0}"' -f $command
    Start-Process $pwsh -Verb RunAs $arg
    return
}

Write-Host 'Elevated'
(Get-Item -Path .\).FullName
$PSBoundParameters | Out-Host


Thanks, this worked. I looked at the $PSBoundParameters and couldn't figure out a way to pass it through. I didn't think about doing the GetEnumerator() Method. Learned something new. I originally tried to splat the variable to no avail.

@Jessie glad it was helpful. GetEnumerator() is required to "enumerate" an IDictionary type in powershell (unlike c# where this method is called implicitly). Splatting the variable  or interpolating it wouldn't help in this case because because it has to be passed as a string to the elevated powershell process and it would result into the type itself instead like i.e. "$(@{ param1 = 'foo'; param2 = 'bar' })" that just results in System.Collections.Hashtable when injected in the string

One question, I noticed in the foreach-object, you added a - in front of the entry for Key. I am curious why that is. I assume without the dash, it would fail?

@Jessie you should also consider that if you try to pass more complex objects (things that aren't value types or strings) to the elevated process this code will fail for sure. Those objects would need to be serialized for that to work properly.

@Jessie yeah the dash is required here because .Key is the parameter, so that code "reconstructs" the arguments used to call the script, i.e. for this answer, $arg becomes -Test1 '123' -Test2 'a string with spaces' when & '$PSCommandPath' is called

@mklement0 thanks, noted the quotes on $pwd. also simplified the logic. cc @Jessie

@mklement0 also true, didn't consider that. fixed. thanks

The edits certainly are cleaner. Could you explain line 27? What does -f mean and why write it out this way instead of calling the variable directly inside the quotes?

-f is the format operator. It injects $command where {0} is in this case. You can also do it in one line but will need parentheses like Start-Process $pwsh -Verb RunAs ($arg -f $command)

It seems, it's not able to pass on a [securestring] parameter. The error states it can't convert system. String to type system.security.securestring. So now I'm wondering if the parameter type can be passed as well.

This method fails if you want to pass complex objects to an elevated process @Jessie already stated that in previous comments. a SecureString is a complex and encrypted type.
